# Extract string between 2 slashes using regex

Tags: regex

I’m trying to extract a string between 2 slashes in a url for example:

```
HTTPS://www.google.com/blabla/ab /what2/what3/lalaalala
```

I want to extract the `ab` which is between 2 slashes in the middle. How can I extract it? It always comes after `blabla` if it helps.

I tried:

```
([^\/]+$)
```

Comment: You can add `/blabla/` before is, omit the anchor `$` and also omit matching spaces if you want `ab` only `\/blabla\/([^\/\s]+)` https://regex101.com/r/CVIetE/1

Comment: But I want just the ab and it gives me also the blabla

Comment: You should get the value of capture group 1, it is highlighted in green in the regex101 link. What is the tool or language?

Comment: @Justaskingaq you can use a positive lookbehind. See my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a positive lookbehind for that: `(?<=...)`

It checks if something exists before your match **without capturing** it in the result.

Here is the regex:

```regex
(?<=\/blabla\/)([^\/]+)
```

Now you only get `ab` as a result.

https://regex101.com/r/4gEsfP/1

---

**Note:** It's "positive" because it checks whether **it is** present, and "lookbehind" because it looks behind the `([^\/]+)` pattern. There are also negative lookbehinds and positive/negative lookaheads.

Some good resource about it: https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind